# Error when updating a PowerBI workspace collection from an arm template

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

We have deployed a PowerBI embedded workspace collection with the following really simple arm template

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "Test Power BI  workspace collection",
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-29",
      "type": "Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "name": "myTestPowerBiCollection",
      "tags": {
        "displayNmae": "Test Power BI workspace collection"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

For deployment we used the well known Powershell command `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` After the creation if we try to execute the command again it fails with the following message

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Resource  Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections 'myTestPowerBiCollection' failed with message
{
   "error": {
     "code": "BadRequest",
     "message": ""
   }
}
```

If we delete the collection and execute again succeeds without a problem. I tried with both the options for the `-Mode` parameter `(Incremental, Complete)` and didn't help, even though Incremental is the default option.

This is a major issue for us as we want to provision the collection as part of our Continuous Delivery and we execute this several times.

Any ideas on how to bypass this problem?

Comment: Hi, I did run in the same issue.
I have an open support ticket about this in the Azure Portal. I will post a update as soon as I have some news.

Comment: @KirKone, did you get a response for your support ticket?

Comment: @DanAnstis yes, the response was this is by design and will not be changed any time soon.

Comment: We also raised a sort call, had the response that PowerBI embedded is being replaced with PowerBI premium. Looks like we should no longer be continuing with new instances of embedded, as they will need to be migrated soon.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned , if PowerBI Workspace Collection name is existed, it will throw expection when we try to deploy the PowerBI Workspace Collection again.

If it is possible to add customized logical code, we could use [Get-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspaceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.powerbiembedded/v2.2.0/get-azurermpowerbiworkspacecollection) to check  whether PowerBI Workspace Collection is existed. If it is existed, it will return PowershellBIworkspaceCollection object, or will throw not found exception.

We also could use [Remove-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspaceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.powerbiembedded/v2.2.0/remove-azurermpowerbiworkspacecollection) command to remove PowerBI Workspace Collection. If PowerBI workspace Connection is existed we could skip to deploy or delete and renew it according to our logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. We thought of this solution but it's not the best one as we are using this template as a nested template during provision a full environment. In order to do all these checks we need to take it out and add extra logic which is not ideal.

In any case I would expect that this should work as it happens with other Azure components. For example deploying twice a storage account doesn't give an error. Is there a certain reason this happens with Power BI collection?

Comment: We could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.

Comment: I posted the idea there to. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/18325225-improve-provisioning-of-power-bi-workspace-collect